# replacement function for hstrerror()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, winsock2

I'm converting a linux socket library to windows, but winsock doesn't have a `hstrerror()` function. `hstrerror()` would take `h_errno` and spit out an error string. Similar to strerror I think. I've looked around but nobody actually says what to replace it with. Other than "It's deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` or `getnameinfo()` instead", I haven't found any mention on what hstrerror is replaced by. Specifically, I have an exception class that uses it. Code below:

```
//
// class socket_h_error
// subclass to record status of extern int h_errno variable
//

class socket_h_error : public socket_error {
public:
    int host_errno;
    //TODO: replace hstrerror()
    explicit socket_h_error(const string& what) :
        socket_error(what + ": " + hstrerror(h_errno)),
        host_errno(h_errno) {}

};
```

I did have to replace `strerror()`, but I saw no mention of that being a possible replacement for `hstrerror()`. It is also non-existant in the winsock2 library, so I have nothing from MS to suggest what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WSAGetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) and [FormatMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage).

WSAGetLastError() is clearly mentioned in all winsock-related functions in MSDN.

Comment: I'm trying this: 
`string s = "";
  FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |  
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
 NULL, herrno,
 MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
 (LPWSTR)&s, 0, NULL);`
It looks super wonky, but its compiling at the moment.

Comment: used a char so I'm not casting. Converted to string after.